# Issues applying redirect/rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've been asked to create some redirects for a website that's being moved and combined with another site. Part of my issue is that the original and new url paths don't match. Not an issue to re-direct the root domain to the new, but then none of the individual redirects work because it continues to append the root domain. The opposite is also true where I can have all the individual redirects work, but not the root.

I've tried standard Redirects and also using a rewrite rule and a combination. A couple of the redirect statements I've put in.

I believe my primary issue is that although the primary domain matches, the client wants to change to sub paths. Examples are:

```
Site1.com/ https://www.Site2.com/ProductCore1/

Site1.com/index.php/our-products/ProductCore1 https://www.Site2.com/ProductCore1/

Site1.com/index.php/our-products/ProductCore1/microsoft-excel https://www.Site2.com/ProductCore1-for-excel/

Site1.com/index.php/our-products/mProductCore1/sap-business-objects https://www.Site2.com/ProductCore1-for-sap-business-objects/

Site1.com/index.php/corporate-menu/contact https://www.Site2.com/contact/
```

Every time I try, the root domain of site1.com properly redirects to site2.com/ProductCore1, but Site1.com/index.php/our-products/ProductCore1/microsoft-excel redirects to https://www.Site2.com/ProductCore1/ProductCore1-for-excel/. It adds in the extra ProductCore1/.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers

Comment: You need to include your existing directives with your attempted redirect directives in-place. By the sounds of it you are probably putting the directives in the wrong order (the standard [`Redirect` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) is prefix-matching). But at the same time you should avoid mixing redirects from both mod_alias and mod_rewrite.

Comment: I didn't mix any of the mod functions and tried with only redirects. After reading up more on the redirect function after seeing your comment about prefix matching I'm guessing my issue is that I can't redirect the root domain to another domain and also redirect specific URL's to new paths because of the prefix matching. You mentioned "wrong order", can I put all the specific URL redirects first and then the redirect to the root domain?